# Does OCaml have general map()/reduce() functions?

Tags: dictionary, polymorphism, ocaml, reduce

In Python map() works on any data that follows the sequence protocol.  It does The Right Thing^TM whether I feed it a string or a list or even a tuple.

Can't I have my cake in OCaml too?  Do I really have no other choice but to look at the collection type I'm using and find a corresponding List.map or an Array.map or a Buffer.map or a String.map?  Some of these don't even exist!  Is what I'm asking for unusual?  I must be missing something.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with having to look up documentation and using the appropriate function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The closest you will get to this is the module [`Enum`](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview/batteries-alpha1/batteries/html/api/Data.Mutable.Enum.html) in [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) (formerly of [Extlib](http://ocaml-extlib.googlecode.com/)). `Enum` defines maps and folds over `Enum.t`; you just have to use a conversion to/from `Enum.t` for your datatype. The conversions can be fairly light-weight, because `Enum.t` is lazy.

What you really want is Haskell-style [type classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), like `Foldable` and `Functor` (which generalizes "maps"). The Haskell libraries define instances of `Foldable` and `Functor` for lists, arrays, and trees. Another relevant technique is the ["Scrap Your Boilerplate" approach](http://www.cs.vu.nl/boilerplate/) to generic programming. Since OCaml doesn't support type classes or [higher-kinded polymorphism](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2579), I don't think you'd be able to express patterns like these in its type system.

Comment: I disagree that wrapping everything in a functor is a "solution" to this problem.

Comment: You are disagreeing with a fact. Look at Okasaki's book for lots of examples and a comparison that explains why OCaml's solution is preferable to type classes in this context.

Comment: No, I am disagreeing with what you consider a solution to the OP's problem. Functors, whatever their advantages, do not provide the kind of syntactically lightweight overloading you get in Python and Haskell.

Comment: If you want brevity then use objects: xs#map f. Either way you can easily express this in OCaml's type system.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-modular-implicits, though I guess it'll take a while to get that merged into ocaml proper.

Answer (score 12):

There are two main solutions in OCaml:

1. Jacques Garrigue already implemented a syntactically-light but inefficient approach for many data structures several years ago. You just wrap the collections in objects that provide a `map` method. Then you can do `collection#map` to use the map function for any kind of collection. This is more general than your requirements because it allows different kinds of data structures to be substituted *at run time*. However, this is not very useful in practice so the approach was never widely adopted.
2. A syntactically-heavier but efficient, robust and static solution is to use functors to parameterize your code over the data structure you are using. This makes it trivial to reuse your code with different data structures. See Markus Mottl's OCaml translations of Okasaki's book "Purely Functional Data Structures" for some great examples.

If you aren't looking for that kind of power and just want brevity then, of course, you can just create a module alias with a shorter name (e.g. module S = String).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each container has a different representation and requires different code for map/reduce to iterate over it. This is why there are separate functions. Most languages provide some sort of general interface for containers (such as the sequence protocol you mentioned) so functions like map/reduce can be implemented abstractly, but this is not done for the types you mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

As long as you define a type t and val compare (: t->t->int) in your module, Map.Make will give you the map you want.